# Windows 8 Metro style ListView auto scroll

Tags: listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using a `ListView` in a Windows 8 Metro style app and I want to programatically make it scroll to a point where a particular item is in the view.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you're working with JavaScript or XAML, but in JavaScript you should be able to just set the `ensureVisible(index)` property of the ListView.  This will make sure that item is visible, scrolling the ListView if necessary:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211820.aspx

In XAML, the `ScrollIntoView(object)` should be what you need.  (For SemanticZoom, see `MakeVisible`.)

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.scrollintoview.aspx