# How do I control the scroll position of a ListView in an MVVM WinRT/XAML Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

This is a similar question to that posed in [How to control the scroll position of a ListBox in a MVVM WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292360/how-to-control-the-scroll-position-of-a-listbox-in-a-mvvm-wpf-app) but, instead, I'm trying to achieve a similar effect from within a Windows Store app: I would like to know how to scroll a `ListView` to the current (or an arbitrary) item from the view model in an MVVM-style app.

There are a couple of limitations in WinRT when compared to WPF:

- The `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property is not supported on `ListView` or related classes (the property exists but using it throws a runtime exception indicating that it is not currently supported);
- There is only partial support for `ICollectionView`, `CollectionViewSource` and other related types.

Fortunately, the `CollectionViewSource` problem is elegantly solved by Bernardo Castilho's solution at CodeProject (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So). Unfortunately, the lack of support for `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` makes solving the remainder of the problem tricky.

There are already several similar questions (e.g. [Windows 8 Metro style ListView auto scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038022/windows-8-metro-style-listview-auto-scroll/12038266#12038266)) but they don't address the problem from an MVVM perspective and don't allow me to maintain a clean MVVM architecture with a minimum of code-behind in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [`ListViewExtensions.ItemToBringIntoView`](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2ca90eed485f#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/ListViewExtensions.cs) attached property from the WinRT XAML Toolkit, which should work similar to how you would bind the `SelectedItem` property but it will bring an item into view instead.